# Apple Rejection for UIBackgroundmodes?

Tags: ios

> ```
> My App has been rejected by apple for the below reason
> ```

```
     Performance - 2.5.4 Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but did not include features
 that
```

In Background our app have to support so that i added the key in info.plist

[image: Image Link]
If i remove that key means the audio could not playing in background mode..Then How is it possible..?

Comment: This means that you have listed that your app plays music or audio in the background, however nowhere within the app is this functionality used or implemented.

Comment: Yeah its used. Basically this app is timer based and we would like to send the sound alert(audio file) to the customer even in background or forground mode